# Добавить два background к одному элементу android

Tags: android, xml, дизайн

Есть элемент ConstraintLayout, нужно к нему в background прописать одновременно градиент и изображение. ниже прописал только градиент, но хочу изображение, которое будет центроваться внизу в ConstraintLayout. использую foreground, как временное решение, но она рисует картинку на всех дочерних элементах

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/mainActivityuStyleForWhiteTheme"
    tools:context=".Activityes.StartActivity">
```

...

```
<style name="mainActivityuStyleForWhiteTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/main_background</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">@drawable/ic_logobackground</item>
    <item name="android:foregroundGravity">right|bottom</item>
</style>
```

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:startColor="@color/first_background_color"
                android:endColor="@color/second_background_color">
            </gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: приложите разметку вашего элемента и опишите более подробно что именно вам хочется увидеть

Comment: Вы же уже используете layer-list, добавьте в него еще один item со вторым изображением... см пример тут https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил второй Item и оформил как нужно следуя документации. Спасибо всем

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:startColor="@color/first_background_color"
                android:endColor="@color/second_background_color">
            </gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logobackground"
        android:gravity="right|bottom"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:bottom="40dp" />

</layer-list>
```